# Is it possible to merge multiple Google Docs into one single Google Apps Script project?

Tags: google-apps-script, merge, google-docs, collaboration

Suppose we work with 5 different documents in Google Docs. It could be Sheets, Slides or Forms, but I'm working with Docs.

Each document have the same Google Apps Script project i.e. the code is identical (it is a very simple project - it replaces some text with another).

**Is there a way to combine these 5 scripts into one single project that includes the 5 docs?** I guess this will be useful because:

- When collaborating, Google don't have to ask us for permission to execute the script several times.
- It is more easy to edit the script (and not 5 times).
- If the script needs to be run on multiple docs at the same time, it is only done once.

Perhaps merging them into one project will cause conflicts, but the project is pretty simple.

Scheme of what I want:

[image: What I want]

Comment: I thought that in your situation, the way that one Google Apps Script uses 5 Google Documents is easier than the way that merging 5 Google Documents in one Google Document. If this way is included in your goal, can I ask you about the detail of your current 5 scripts?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for the feedback. Merging the documents is a good idea, but I need to keep them apart. I ask if it is possible to merge the 5 scripts. Please see the edited question.

Comment: It is definitely possible. But you may still wish to have different scripts because the code for each type of container is quite different.

Comment: What response are you expecting?

Comment: @Cooper I see your edited comment. What do you mean by "container"? The script only replaces one text by another, just that. It would be more easy to have one script doing the same thing to 5 documents rather than 5 scripts. The response I am expecting is the one that can merge 5 scripts into one script, and keep modifying those five documents.

Comment: Well in order to merge five scripts into one you are going to have to provide five documents with five different scripts and explain what they all do before we can begin.  But the code for a Slides Doc, a Google Doc, a spreadsheet and a form are very different so it will not always be possible to combine them depending upon the complexity.  I think you should try writing some code of your own in order to get an idea of what's involved.

Comment: @Cooper The code is not necessary in this question. I posted a scheme that focus on clarify the question, if it is unclear ask me. However I found the solution I expected, I wrote it as an answer. If you want to improve the answer please do it. If not, thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I found [this article](https://www.labnol.org/code/19892-merge-multiple-google-documents) that helped me to find the solution:

It only required the `id` of the five documents:

```
function mergeGoogleDocs() {
  var docIDs = ['documentID_1', 'documentID_2', 'documentID_3', 'documentID_4', 'documentID_5'];
  for (var id in docIDs) {
    doSomething(docIDs[id]);
  }
}

function doSomething(id) {
  // Put the code here using 'id' to open the document
}
```

This makes things easier, because every time I run the script (from one document, say "Doc 1") the function `mergeGoogleDocs` modify all the documents at once.