# Is it possible to add custom menus for several Google Docs at the same time?

Tags: google-apps-script, menu, google-docs

Suppose we work with 5 different documents in Google Docs.

I have a master/main document which has a Google Script in it (it is a very simple project - it replaces some text with another). A MWE of the script is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70738462/11617040):

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('First item', 'mergeGoogleDocs')
    .addToUi();
}

function mergeGoogleDocs() {
  var docIDs = ['documentID_1', 'documentID_2', 'documentID_3', 'documentID_4', 'documentID_5'];
  for (var id in docIDs) {
    doSomething(docIDs[id]);
  }
}

function doSomething(id) {
  // Put the code here using 'id' to open the document
}
```

However, when I run `onOpen`, the button only appears on the master/main document (say "Doc 1"). **I would like to have this button on every Document (Doc 1, Doc 2, ... Doc 5). Is it possible?**

Comment: `DocumentApp.getUi()` is used for the active Document which has the container-bound script including this script. So in your situation, unfortunately, from the active Document, `DocumentApp.getUi()` cannot be used for other Documents except for the active Document.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for the information! Is there another class like `DocumentApp.getUi()` but that can work with multiple active Documents?

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, `DocumentApp.getUi()` is put in a container-bound script of Google Document, and when you want to try to run this script for other Google Document, unfortunately, that cannot be achieved. If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Comment: For example, when you want to create the custom menu when each Document is opened, how about putting the script to each Document? If you want to achieve this using a script, you can do this using Google Apps Script API. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Putting the script to each Document is not a good idea, that's my problem `:(` It would be great to work with just one script, and create the button on every document. If it is not achievable with `DocumentApp.getUi()`, with what other method could it be achieved?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike No problem! If you came up with an idea please post it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that unfortunately, in the current stage, there are not methods for directly achieving your goal. So I proposed a workaround. I apologize for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the best option would be to serve `doSomething(id)` function from a library, that all documents in `mergeGoogleDocs` share.

You will still need to initiate menu in each document separately, because as Tanaike stated `DocumentApp.getUi()` is reserved for container-bound projects only.

Comment: What are the benefits of using a library? Will we still need to create a project for each document? I never worked with libraries in Google Apps Script, so if you can guide me I would appreciate it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Main advantage of the library is that you have a centralized way of serving information. That means, that if some function changes you only need to change it in the library not in all projects which use this function. You can serve library as head version, which means, that you dont even need to republish it at every change. In your case you want multiple sheets to share one function, that's why I suggested using library.